# Can't stop logging all queries that mongoose fire in the application

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

[I want MongoDB to stop logging all the queries make by node.js using mongoose. At my CMD that started with command 'mongod --dbpath "C:/data" --replSet rs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5kQZ.png)

I'm Using Node.js v10.16.3 with mongoose v5.7.5

This is how I'm connecting in my server.js file -

```js
const options = {
  auth: {
    user: "tyd******",
    password: "*****cgt"
  },
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  autoIndex: true, // Don't build indexes
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 10000, // Give up initial connection after 10 seconds
  socketTimeoutMS: 45000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
  family: 4, // Use IPv4, skip trying IPv6
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, // Timeout after 5s instead of 30s
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, options).then(
    () => { 
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
    },
    err => { 
        /** handle initial connection error */ 
        console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
        process.exit();
    }
);
```

Please tell, if there is anything I can add in Option while connecting to mongoDb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "Start MongoDB Enterprise Edition as a Windows Service" as I'm using Enterprise Edition.

I need to use the command at cmd `net start MongoDB`. 
For stop, the MongoDB as service command is `net stop MongoDB`.

If the mongod.cnf is configured correctly the MongoDB server will successfully start.

File mongod.cnf can found at path `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin` as my version was 4.2 accordingly you can find.

For Further if anybody need help go to [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-windows/#start-mongodb-enterprise-edition-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is start the mongod process in background mode(using `--fork` option), with this, you don't get to see the logs anymore. So this would be the command you run in your CMD:

```
mongod --dbpath "C:/data" --replSet rs --fork
```

Comment: Not able to use '--fork'.
`mongod --auth --port 34112 --dbpath "C:\data\database09" --replSet rs --fork `
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--fork' .

try 'mongod --help' for more information

Comment: Ooooh... I just saw in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#cmdoption-mongod-fork) that the `--fork` option is not supported on windows. The other option to have the logs go away is to start the mongod process as a service, the service controller can take care of making the logs disappear. How to start mongod process as a windows service is properly documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-mongodb-community-edition-as-a-windows-service), please, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tunmee. From your last comment, I got to know I have to search for "Start MongoDB Enterprise Edition as a Windows Service" as I'm using Enterprise Edition. 

I need to use the command at cmd `net start MongoDB`.
if the mongod.cnf is configured correctly the MongoDB server will successfully start.
For Further if anybody need help go to [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-windows/#start-mongodb-enterprise-edition-as-a-windows-service)